# Return 401 from WCF service

Tags: http, wcf, http-status-code-401

How can I return a HTTP 401 from a WCF service?

Comment: Are doing the [OperationContract, WebInvoke] [Service] thing?

Answer (score 6):

If you are programming a REST-service it can be done this way:

```
private IWebOperationContext context = new WebOperationContextWrapper(WebOperationContext.Current); // Get the context

context.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized; // Set the 401
```

Answer (score 6):

```
throw new WebFaultException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Notes:

> MSDN: When using a WCF REST endpoint (WebHttpBinding and
>   WebHttpBehavior or WebScriptEnablingBehavior) the HTTP status code on
>   the response is set accordingly. However, WebFaultException can be
>   used with non-REST endpoints and behaves like a regular
>   FaultException.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the WebServiceHost2 factory from the WCF REST Starter Kit, you can also throw specific `WebProtocolException` and specify a HTTP return code:

[image]
<sub>(source: [robbagby.com](http://www.robbagby.com/wp-content/uploads/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/image_thumb_5.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [robbagby.com](http://www.robbagby.com/wp-content/uploads/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/image_thumb_10.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [robbagby.com](http://www.robbagby.com/wp-content/uploads/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/image_thumb_12.png))</sub>

There's also a `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` which corresponds to the 401 status code.

See Rob Bagby's excellent blog post [Effective Error Handling with WCF REST](http://www.robbagby.com/rest/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/) for more detail on the various ways of specifying HTTP return codes. (screenshots are from Rob's blog post - he deserves all the credit for this.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you need to do the authorization check, you could do it in an `HttpModule` using something like the following:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Not exactly true...you could do this with ANY of the xHttpBindings.